# Dictionary key manipulation using a mapping relation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm wondering, let's say I have the following data structure:

```
fields = {'Name': 'Foo', 'Surname': 'Bar', 'Email': 'foo.bar@email.com', 'Privacy': 'true'}
```

I also have the following mapping relationship function:

```
def get_account_fields_map():
    return {
        'Name': 'first_name',
        'Surname': 'last_name',
        'Email': 'email',
        'Privacy': 'remarketing_consent'
    }

fields_map = get_account_fields_map()
```

What would be the best and most performant technique, to rename the keys of `fields` dictionary using the `fields_map`?

I'm thinking it may need a combination of:

```
_dict[new_key] = __dict.pop(old_key)
```

And the `map()` function, and some sort of apply function which translates they keys? Not sure...any suggestions would be appreciated.

N.B. I also know that one of the field values is 'true'...I'm using an XML SOAP API. XD

***Edit***: N.B. Also, I would need to handle if `fields` had a key value pair which didn't have a mapping in the `fields_map`...for this case, I am happy to drop that key - value pair from the dict...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new dictionary:

```
fields = {fields_map[k]:v for k,v in fields.items()}
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/ExpensiveBuoyantSearch)

In case the key is not found, you can use [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) and return the original key as new key:

```
fields = {fields_map.get(k, k):v for k,v in fields.items()}
```

Comment: Great answer - but...could I throw a spanner in the works?

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos what do you mean throw a spanner?

Comment: It's an English turn of phrase - apologies. I have added an additional constraint in my question, take a look at ***EDIT***

Comment: Essentially, under this case the situation throws a `KeyError`, that's where my mapping was bottlenecking...

Comment: I have added an answer to this thread, with the neccessary catch for the issue describe. Thank you for your efforts tho! I definitely couldn't have reached it without this input.

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos, you can use `.get` and use the same key as default, check the edit.

Comment: Works like a charm, and accepted because it is more Pythonic than my own solution/answer ... plus you did 99% of the heavy lifting. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Most performant way is to change the key names when you are iterating the dict for some other reason (say, input validation), like so:

```
def read_input(fields):
    fields_map = get_account_fields_map()
    ret = {}
    for k, v in fields.items():
        ret[fields_map[k]] = validate(v)
    return ret
```

Most Pythonic is dict comprehension:

```
fields = {fields_map[k]: v for k, v in fields.items()}
```

Comment: Are you sure building a new dictionary with a pure Python loop is the most performant?  Have a reference?  I ask because I believe that (a) resizing the hash table periodically will be expensive if there is a lot of data and (b) comprehensions are executed at the C level and tend to be pretty quick.

Comment: @yardsale8 yes you are right from the low level performace point of view, if OP's program is simple enough the dict comprehension will be faster. But in real world application I found that (no reference for this, just experience) the most performant approach is to minimize iterations. Sure enough the data will be iterated for some reason (validation, normalization, etc..) and the hash table resizing it's probably already happening for those reasons, I found that adding the keymapping logic in those unavoidable loops is better. I believe optimization depends mostly on the rest of OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a dict comprehension, something like :

```
{fields_map[k]:v for k,v in fields.items()}
```

I have no clue if it would be the best and most performant technique though.

Answer (score 0):

So all of the above solutions would work, if a mapping relationship was very much definied. However, for the case where, for example, fields was:

```
fields = {
    'Name': 'Foo', 
    'Surname': 'Bar', 
    'Email': 'foo.bar@email.com', 
    'Privacy': 'true', 
    'SomeUnmappedFieldKey': 'value' 
}
```

Would throw a `KeyError` just by using:

`fields = {fields_map[k]:v for k, v in fields.items()}`

Having used the springboard by @Netwave, therefore it looks like the most comprehensize way to avoid `KeyErrors` or discrepancies between the mapping relation and the original `dict` would be to use:

```
fields = {fields_map[k]:v for k, v in fields.items() if k in fields_map}
```

Which gives:

```
fields = {
    'first_name': 'Foo', 
    'last_name': 'Bar', 
    'email': 'foo.bar@email.com', 
    'remarketing_consent': 'true', 
}
```

From @Netwave 's suggestion, there is a slight nuance with this and my solution, such that:

```
fields = {fields_map.get(k, k):v for k,v in fields.items()}
```

Would give the following:

```
{
    'first_name': 'Foo', 
    'last_name': 'Bar', 
    'email': 'foo.bar@email.com', 
    'remarketing_consent': 'true,
    'SomeUnmappedFieldKey': value
}
```

So one method retains the key if there is no mapping, and one drops it if it is not in the mapping. Use whichever is best for your use case.